# How can I detect if an LV line is powered?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I'd like to turn some redstone on and off, depending on whether an LV line powered by solar panels is on or off. Is there a way of doing this?

They are IndustrialCraft Solar panels, which are powering a batbox, which is in turn powering a copper cable, the status of which I'd like to query.

I am using the Direwolf FTB modpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use a [Detector Cable](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Detector_Cable). It can accept up to 32 EU/p and emits a Redstone signal if energy is flowing through it. However, it has a very high energy loss (0.5 EU per block).
2. Use the BatBox or equivalent storage unit itself. If you right-click it, you should have a button with Redstone dust on it. Click that until you get the "emit if empty" behavior. This will make the BatBox output a Redstone signal if it doesn't have energy to send. It's smart enough to output a signal if it has *some* leftover energy, but not enough to send a packet.

Comment: Batbox is the way to go, detector cable doesn't work, as it requires current to be flowing - which it isn't at first because the recycler is empty.

Comment: Although, even that doesn't work. Partially full means it does not emit if it is full!

Comment: @fredley Really? I thought it would, sorry. Anyway, easy enough to fix. Change to "emit if empty" and invert the signal.